# React router keeps unmounting component while pressing on active link

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a simple app with react router v4.0. There is *Home* and *About* links that can be pressed and appropriate Route will be rendered on a page.

I noticed that when clicking on an already active *Home* link twice or more - *Home* component gets re-mounted each time which is unexpected behaviour.

This happens only when `Route` element is not directly in `Router` but is in a wrapper function `App`. Ex: https://codesandbox.io/s/wwnxxqy4m5 (press Home link and check console logs)

```
const Root = () => (
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
);
```

If I put routes directly to `Router` component `Home` is not unmounted each time.

```
const Root = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={withRouter(Home)}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={withRouter(About)}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Does anyone have ideas, why unmounting of *Home* is forced when wrapper function is used?

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you component is mounted and unmounted again is because to the route you are returning a new component everytime, with `component={withRouter(Home)}`. So everytime a route path matches, it checks the component prop and each time a new instance of your Home component is created and returned.

In your case you don't actually need to wrap your component with `withRouter` since the component is directly rendered by the Route and will receive the `Route` params. However In a case when you need to wrap with `withRouter`, just create a single instance of a component and then export and import that instance and not create a new one everytime

**[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxvl5ym769)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shubham. withRouter - in this case is just for a simplified example reasons. In real world app i have RequireAuth higher order function that I am using in component={RequireAuth(Home)}. I would like to agree with a statement, that "every time new instance is created", but that doesn't explain the reason, why Route used directly in Routes without App doesn't cause this behaviour

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't happen, but the same thing is mentioned in this github issue: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4630